# RCurl getURLContent with HTTPS doesn't work log="Error: Forbidden"

Tags: ssl, https, rcurl

I have an issue with the package RCurl on a specific website.

I would like to extract data from a specific https url.

After some readings on SSL problems I could encounter with secured HTTP, here is my R code:

myurl <- "https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Magic+Origins/Day%27s+Undoing"

getURLContent(myurl, cainfo = "C:/myfolder/cacert.pem", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)

or

getURLContent(myurl, cainfo = "C:/myfolder/cacert.pem")

My problem is that neither of those 2 lines works. All I get is that message:
Error : Forbidden

When I use this code on an other https url it works:
getURLContent("https://www.google.com", cainfo = "C:/myfolder/cacert.pem")

I really don't understand why this particular website doesn't work